# File Gets Written In The First Condition Only

Tags: c#, text-files

I am trying to write in a text file and my condition is if a writing already exists in that file, then it should print 'Another Line Added - The Message'. So I've tried the following but it throws exception 'it is being used by another process' and I can understand I am doing something wrong:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
   string path = @"C:\Users\AT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Sample_App\Sample_App\app_data\log.txt"; //File path

   FileStream stream;

   if (File.Exists(path))
   {
     stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite); //This section used to read and write operations

     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) //Writing words to the text file
     {
       string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path); //Here is the exception - It's being used by another process

        if (lines.Length > 0)
        {
           writer.WriteLine("\n" + "Another Line Added - " + message);
           writer.Flush();

           stream.Close();
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
       /**If text file is created for the first time - Starts**/
       stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create); //This section used to read and write operations

       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) //Writing words to the text file
       {
          writer.WriteLine(message);
          writer.Flush();

          stream.Close();
       }
       /**If text file is created for the first time - Ends**/
    }
}
```

Now what happens the file is created for the first with a text included '**Hello World!!** and when I add another text to it, then I am expecting to get the following output:

**Expected output:**

Hello World!! ---- Only for the first time else

Another Line Added - Hello World!!

Another Line Added - Hello World!!

Another Line Added - Hello World!!

I would expect some ideas or advices to make it work and let me know what I am doing wrong. It's totally a simple one. I would like to do one more thing in the file like the below:

**Output:**

1) Hello World!!

2) Hello World!!

**Note:** In  the above output, I am incrementing the numbers whenever I run the console application. That means if the same writing exists, then it should increment by one. I was expecting a simple Linq to do like this and is it possible to do in a simple way: (In this case, do I need to create any model to get over the text file?)

```
var query = (var c in fileName
         select c);

foreach(var item in query)
{
  //Do something here
}
```

I've gone through the followings but unable to get the above work yet:

[MSDN - 01](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN - 02](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.ReadAllLines(path);` creates another stream.

Placing it above the FileStream should fix it

Because you are using the `using` keyword you don't have to close the stream

```
public static void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        string path = @"log.txt"; //File path

        FileStream stream;

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite); //This section used to read and write operations

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) //Writing words to the text file
            {
                if (lines.Length > 0)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("\n" + "Another Line Added - " + message);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /**If text file is created for the first time - Starts**/
            stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create); //This section used to read and write operations

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) //Writing words to the text file
            {
                writer.WriteLine(message);
                writer.Flush();
            }
            /**If text file is created for the first time - Ends**/
        }
    }
```

Comment: Placed and got it worked. Thanks. Could you please brief a little about the second approach that I am trying to increment by one in the text file?

Answer (score 1):

Handling raw streams are a valid way to do file handling, if you are transported back in time. We have newer .NET Framework versions and simpler and better file handling functions:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
   string path = @"C:\Users\AT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Sample_App\Sample_App\app_data\log.txt"; //File path

   if (File.Exists(path))
   {
     File.AppendAllLines(path, new[]{ "Another line added - Hello world" });
   }
   else
   {
     File.AppendAllLines(path, new[]{ "Hello World!!" });
   }
}
```

An example of actually taking into account the contents of a file:

```
public void WriteMessageWithLineNumbers(string message)
{
   string path = @"C:\Users\AT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Sample_App\Sample_App\app_data\log.txt"; //File path

   if (File.Exists(path))
   {
     var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

     var nextLine = string.Format("{0} - Hello World", lines.Length + 1)

     File.AppendAllLines(path, new[]{ nextLine });
   }
   else
   {
     File.AppendAllLines(path, new[]{ "1 - Hello World!!" });
   }
}
```

Comment: I got it working. Thanks. Could you please brief a little about the second approach that I am trying to increment by one in the text file?

Comment: @AT-2016 Added a second example of handling file contents.

Comment: Good one @nvoigt . It's really easy to work with. But I am keen to know if I try it in another way like using Linq to get the control of the text file, should it be wise to use model or any thing related to it?

Comment: @AT-2016 That question is a bit broad for a comment. LinQ is for querying (that's the Q in LinQ), not for manipulating. You can do manipulation on the result or as a side effect (bad!) of a LinQ statement. Maybe you should ask another question about that.

Answer (score 1):

`StreamWriter` for text writing does not require `Stream` parameter for the constructor. It can use directly the path of the file itself. In this way you can omit `FileStream`:

```
    public static void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        var path = @"../../sth.txt"; //File path
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);//This section used to read and write operations
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true)) //Writing words to the text file
            {
                if (lines.Length > 0)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Another Line Added - " + message);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(message);
                }

                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /**If text file is created for the first time - Starts**/
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path)) //Writing words to the text file
            {
                writer.WriteLine(message);
                writer.Flush();
            }
            /**If text file is created for the first time - Ends**/
        }
    }
```